# Suggestions for a C# custom tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

Has anybody got any suggestions for a custom tabcontrol implemented in C# and which adheres to these criteria:

- Allows the tabs to be placed along the side of the control.
- Tab text must read horizontally.
- Allow custom colouring.
- Open source or no cost.

I prefer not to get my hands dirty with *ownerdrawing* if a solution already exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably don't have a need for this anymore but anyone else who stumbles upon it might find it useful.

I found this tabcontrol on CodeProject it is also very easy to Draw your own tabs with it, they even give you a example on the site.

[Y(et)A(nother)TabControl](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/yatabcontrol.aspx)

A couple more tab controls.

[TabStrip Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/tabstrips.aspx)

[TabStrips: A TabControl in the Visual Studio 2005 way!](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/TabStrip.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The tab control in WPF fulfills all of your requirements. You can override the template and go to town on it.